# Ajax.BeginForm() not calling the method and calls directly Javascript method in OnSuccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with ASP MVC 5 and I have been using *Ajax.BeginForm()* in many of my views, but there has only been issues on one of the view. **As I submit a form using Ajax.BeginForm, the method defined was not called, there isn't any errors triggered or catched, and it goes directly to the callback of *OnSuccess* without loading any actions in the method.**

I have tried to search for a similar issue and found that it could be because of typo or the type of model but I have checked everything, there isn't such mistakes at all. Hence I would like to know if any of us here encountered similar problems.

Just to test things out, I tried simple *Post*'ing and it doesn't work as well.

Stats.cshtml

```
@model Example.ViewModels.StatsViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "Statistic", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="alert('test')" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-filter m-r-sm"></i>Filter</button>
}
```

StatisticController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult Test(StatsViewModel test)
{       
    StatsViewModel vm = new StatsViewModel
    {
       [...]
    };
    return PartialView("Test", vm);
}
```

Results : the alert is triggered first

P.S.:

- I have checked if the method is called by placing debug points in the IDE and only this method here isn't pausing at any debug point
- I have checked if i have the *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js* included and evidently, it is present and hence I have lost any possible clue of why is it skipping the method call and falling directly into OnSuccess callback.

Thank you in advance for any possible solutions.

Comment: Did you check the browser console in the dev tools? The network tab? Is there a POST xhr happening at all?

Comment: @ChrisG yes, and there is a POST xhr for the method Test indicating that it has been called and return Http Status OK (200)

Comment: What's the response content? Does it say "Test"?

Comment: Yes, it says that the method has been called but in the application's logs, there aren't any trace of the method being called

Comment: Is it possible the URL is wrong? If the URL points to your server and the browser is getting a 200, your server must be answering. Again, what is the contents of the response?

Comment: @ChrisG By checking according to what you mention about the URL, it seems that the action is calling another main action and passed the "Test" action as a string parameter. Seems like I have found the real problem but I am not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the problem occur on posting the form to an action method.
Resolution.

1. You must add
   `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` to your `web config <appSettings>`
2. In the view page add the following JS file references

- `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"></script>`
- `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was because of one of the routes in the same controller that accepts a string as its route parameter.

It is not supposed to be redirected to that but since the other routes aren't explicitly declared, hence it was redirected to that route by default when Ajax does the POST.

Thank you for the help.